# rails: how to check value in next view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I'm trying to make a quiz app.
Such that each question in the Question table has the following fields:

qn, correct, option1, option2, option3

This is my questions_controller.rb so far...

```
def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

def answer
  #not working
  @answered = Question.find(params[:id])
end
```

and this is the page I'm coming from...

```
Shuffled from question
<ul>
<% [@question.correct, @question.option1, @question.option2, @question.option3].shuffle.each do |b| %>
  <li><%= link_to b, answer_path %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Clicking on a link takes it to the answer.html.erb page ok, but once I'm there
how do I know which link was clicked? Or, how do I get this out of the controller.

I can't use find(params...) because they are from different fields and I don't want to look up a question anyway...

I know you guys are rolling your eyes but I've looked at a few similar questions but can't quite put it together.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you say `how do I know which link was clicked?` do you want to know which attribute from `correct, option1, option2, option3` was clicked ?

Comment: you are not passing any paramter to your answer_path that is why your code not working. see below answer

Comment: @swap.nil - Yes. Exactly.

Comment: you may find the below solution useful... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the attribute value in `answer` by passing it in the `params`

```
<%= link_to b, answer_path(:id => @question.id, :option => b) %>
```

and get it in controller action `params[:option]`

**EDIT**

If you want to know which option was clicked then you can do

```
<% %w(correct option1 option2 option3).shuffle.each do |b| %>
  <li><%= link_to @question.try(b), answer_path(:id => @question.id, :option => b) %></li>
<% end %>
```

and in controller

```
question = Question.find(params[:id])
option_value = question.try(params[:option])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= link_to b, answer_path(:id => @question.id) %>
```